# how to copy dependencies to a directory in buildr?

Tags: buildr

I have ./lib directory in my project, how can i copy dependencies to this directory in buildr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the tasks representing the dependencies for a project using `project.compile.dependencies`. You can get the path from a file task using `#to_s`. So you should be able to do something like this:

```
cp project.compile.dependencies.collect { |t| t.to_s }, project.path_to('lib')
```